# Why is my code jumping from def main() to def is_even(n)?

Tags: python

I am following CS50P on YouTube and learning parity in conditionals. I visualised the code to get a better understanding and confused as to why my code is jumping from main() to def is_even(n) in the second step of execution.

```
1   def main():
2       x = int(input("whats the value of x? "))
3       if is_even(x):
4           print("even")
5       else:
6           print("odd")
7   
8   def is_even(n):
9       if n % 2 == 0:
10          return True
11      else:
12          return False 
13  
14  main()
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is not nested properly. Please look at proper python indentation

Comment: @Kwright02 thank you i just copied it. but the code is properly indented in my vs code and it runs perfectly. could you please explain why it jumps from def main() to is_even(). thank you

Comment: Because the first thing that happens is the functions get _defined_, first `main` then `is_even`. Then one of them (`main`) gets _called_.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the display wrong. It's not jumping from `main()` to `def is_even(n):`. The display is saying that the `def` just executed (defining the `is_even` function), and the next thing that's going to happen is the `main()` line, which will call the `main` function.

Note that the `is_even` function itself has not executed. The code to *define* `is_even` has executed.